# Azure VMs restart unexpectedly

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-vm-role

This is a problem is related to worker role hosted VM. I have a simple worker role, which spans a process inside of it. The process spawned is the 32 bit compiled TCPServer application. Worker role has a endpoint defined in it, the TCPserver is bound to the end point of the Worker role. So when I connect to my worker role endpoint, and send something, TCPserver recieves it , processes it returns something back. So here the endpoint of the worker role which is exposed to outside world, internally connects to TCPserver.

`string port = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints[""TCPsocket].IPEndpoint.Port.ToString();`

```
            var myProcess = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(localstorage.RootPath, "TCPServer.exe"))
                {
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    UseShellExecute = true,
                    WorkingDirectory = localstorage.RootPath,
                    Arguments = port
                }
            };
```

It was working fine. But suddenly sever stopped to respond. When I checked in portal, VM role was restarting automatically. But it never succeeded. It was showing `Role Initializing..` status. Manual stop and start also din't work. I redeployed the same package without any change in the code. This time deployment itself failed.

`Warning: All role instances have stopped
- There was no endpoint listening at https://management.core.windows.net/<SubscriptionID>/services/hostedservices/TCPServer/deploymentslots/Production that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.`

But after some time again I tried to deploy, it worked fine.
Can anyone tell me what would be the problem?

**Update:**

```
  public override void Run()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("RasterWorker entry point called", "Information");
        string configVal = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString");
        CloudStorageAccount _storageAccount = null;
        _storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(configVal); // accepts storage cridentials and create storage account
        var localstorage = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("MyLocalStorage");
        CloudBlobClient _blobClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        bool flag = false;

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(30000);
            if (!flag)
            {
                if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(localstorage.RootPath, "test.ppm")))
                {
                    CloudBlobContainer _blobContainer = _blobClient.GetContainerReference("reports");
                    CloudBlob _blob = _blobContainer.GetBlobReference("test.ppm");
                    _blob.UploadFile(Path.Combine(localstorage.RootPath, "test.ppm"));
                    Trace.WriteLine("Copy to blob done!!!!!!!", "Information");
                    flag = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine("Copy Failed-> File doesnt exist!!!!!!!", "Information");
                }
            }
            Trace.WriteLine("Working", "Information");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent your worker role to be restart you'll need to block the **Run** method of your entry point class.

> If you do override the Run method, your code should block
>   indefinitely. If the Run method returns, **the role is automatically recycled** by raising the Stopping event and calling the OnStop method
>   so that your shutdown sequences may be executed before the role is
>   taken offline.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.run.aspx

You need to make sure that, whatever happens, you never return from the **Run** method if you want to keep the role alive.

Now, if you're hosting the TCPServer in a console application (I'm assuming you're doing this since you pasted the Process.Start code), you'll need to block the **Run** method after starting the process.

```
public override void Run()
{
   try
   {
      Trace.WriteLine("WorkerRole entrypoint called", "Information");

      var myProcess = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(localstorage.RootPath, "TCPServer.exe"))
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = true,
                WorkingDirectory = localstorage.RootPath,
                Arguments = port
            }
        };
        myProcess.Start();

      while (true)
      {
         Thread.Sleep(10000);
         Trace.WriteLine("Working", "Information");
      }
      // Add code here that runs in the role instance
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      Trace.WriteLine("Exception during Run: " + e.ToString());
      // Take other action as needed.
   }
}
```

PS: This has nothing to do with your deployment issue, I assume this was a coincidence

Comment: I agree with your point. As you said the run method will never return since there is a infinite while loop in it. I am doing the same way that you told above. Only change is that, I start my process in the `OnStart()` method. Then enters to`Run()`.

Comment: I suggest you wrap the code in your while loop in a try/catch block. If the upload fails or the test.ppm file is in use, ... your process will crash and the WorkerRole will reboot.

Comment: Sure I will try with that. But I don't think that will create problem. Because, [1]. Sure file will not be in use, since my spawned process creates it in few secs, and I am waiting for 30 secs before i access it. [2]. I saw in WADLogs, file gets copied succesfully message and its done only once. Because I have a flag that is set to True once copy is over. So thereafter it will never tou

Comment: OK. An other option is to try and remote desktop to the machine when it restarts (you might need to try a few times before getting a connection) and verify the event viewer (Application log) to see if you can find any errors.